# Sync read and write

Tags: c, sockets

I'm using `read` and `write` functions to communicate between client and server.

If server use two times `write`, in **Wireshark** I can see that two packets was send, but my `read` function concat two packets in one buffer

**Question:**
It is possible to my `read` function read only one payload at one time?
I dont want reduce buffer

**Ex:**
Situation now:

> Send(8bytes) Send(8bytes)
>
> Read, read 16 bytes

**I want**

> Send(8 bytes) Send(8Bytes)
>
> Read, read 8 bytes(first packet)
>
> Read, read 8 bytes(second packet)

Answer (score 3):

TCP/IP gives you an ordered byte stream. Reads and writes are not guaranteed to have the same boundaries, as you have seen.

To see where messages begin and end, you need to add extra information to your protocol to provide this information. A workable simple approach is to have a byte count at the start of each message. Read the byte count, then you know how many more bytes to read to get the complete message and none of the next message.

Comment: that approach would also help in cases when one `read()`read *less* then what has been sent by one `write()`. That can (and, by Murphy's lay, will) happen too

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Yes, exactly. TCP gives you a stream of bytes without boundaries.

Comment: Moreover, these characteristics are not specific to TCP.  The `read()` and `write()` system interfaces *in general* do not inherently communicate message boundaries.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That is slightly less true. You can use `read()` and `write()` on a UDP socket and have message boundaries respected.

Comment: @janm, my point is not that there are no cases where you get message boundaries faithfully reproduced, but rather that these system interfaces themselves make no promises about that.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, I agree `read()` and `write()` themselves do not provide those guarantees. I did say "slightly less true"!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to synchronize server and client use something like semaphores or you can send read/write bytes and this avoid sending information before client read it. Or if you know exactly length of message you can separate readed bytes. If you make buffer exact length of message remain bytes will be lost so make a server sending information when reader read previous message or extend buffer and separate multiple messages.

Comment: The remaining bytes won't be lost with TCP/IP, they will be available on the next read.

Comment: He dont say which protocol use, maybe he use UDP.

Comment: He cannot be using UDP because his two writes are merged into one.